# Inline CKEditor toolbar has no alignment buttons for h2 elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

(also on their demo page http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline)

Why is this the case? Even if I take their inline sample (http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-02-08-08-51/standard/samples/inlineall.html) and remove the js code for separate toolbars for heading blocks, I still don't get the alignment option.

I'd like to give users the option to align headings. What am I missing?

I'm also not getting other "block" options like BulletedList, but that's less of an issue.

**UPDATE:** To repeat the issue you need to have contenteditable="true" applied to a heading element. So, one fix is to wrap the heading in a div with the contenteditable="true". But this doesn't help my case.

Answer (score 6):

You need the Justify plugin since CKEditor 4.

1. [Download Justify plugin here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/justify)
2. Paste it into ckeditor/plugins/
3. Add the plugin to your ckeditor.

Here is the javascript code :

```
$(function() {
    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
});
```

You don't have anything more to do, Justify plugin will be automatically added to the `paragraph` toolbarGroup

**EDIT**

By `alignment`, I thought you were talking about `right|center|left` align.

Here, for h tags, we've got those groups :

```
if ( element.is( 'h1', 'h2', 'h3' ) || element.getAttribute( 'id' ) == 'taglist' ) {
    editor.on( 'configLoaded', function() {
       editor.config.removePlugins = 'colorbutton,find,flash,font,' +
          'forms,iframe,image,newpage,removeformat,scayt,' +
          'smiley,specialchar,stylescombo,templates,wsc';
       editor.config.toolbarGroups = [
          { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'links' ] },
          { name: 'undo' },
          { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'selection', 'clipboard' ] },
          { name: 'about' }
       ];
    });
}
```

`['basicstyles', 'links', 'undo', 'selection', 'clipboard', 'about']`, there's no `align` group, simply add it.

You don't event have to modify anything after a new CKEditor install, this group is already in the inline basic configuration

Comment: i think that problem is that on same page (inlineall.html in ckeditor samples) h2 tag with contenteditable doesnt have aligment toolbar while div tags do, even when we remove different initiation code for h tags, question is why is that

Comment: @Zee exactly. I tried your suggestion zessx with no luck, still the same. One thing I did notice is that there are other toolbar buttons missing text direction.

Comment: *like text direction and block quotes

Comment: I misunderstood you about `alignment` option, because you shouldn't have any problem with `align` group after a new install. See my edit.

Comment: No, you understood correctly, I was talking about that alignment. The alignment buttons are still missing in your jsFiddle. I am seeing the block quote button though, so there isn't a connection between them  then.

Comment: Ah, well done, it works with your jsfiddle code! I still have to figure out why it's not working for me. Give me a while and I'll come back to give you the bounty

Comment: While comparing the code I found that the difference is that, when you add contenteditable="true" to an h2 element it still doesn't work. Your fiddle has it added to a wrapping div, and that's why it works. Any idea why it doesn't work on an h2 element?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to enable align buttons on `h2` editable. CKEditor cannot modify editable container, because that change simply wouldn't be visible in data got from editor, because `editor.getData()` returns `innerHTML` not `outerHTML`.

I'm also afraid that simple bypass doesn't exist. You can wrap `h2` with editable `div`, set enterMode=BR, remove buttons like format combo from toolbar, but that would be still incomplete solution, because user will be able to remove that `h2`, split it by pasting some block elements or leave it somehow and write outside it. This issues may be fixed, but I guess that you don't want to spend on this another month :).

Comment: Ah thank you for your reply... I guess all I can do now is wait(or help) for the ckeditor devs to fix this, if they even see it as an issue.

Comment: Accidentally I am one of CKE core devs :P I understand the problem, but it's definitely not a bug. It has to work this way. We may consider adding new feature solving your issue, but I don't have an idea what could it be. It would require changing editor's assumptions and we'll avoid this. PS. You can always write your own plugin adding your own align buttons which will just change `text-align` on editable. This is the easiest solution I can think of.

Comment: Hah, good to know! :)
Your plugin suggestion sounds good though. I might just try it! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar for the explaination ! The easiest solution will still be to wrap your `<h2>` into a `<div contenteditable="true"`. If you don't want users to be able to change this `h2` into something else, maybe you shouldn't use a WYSIWYG editor for it, but a simple formatted `<input type="text">`.

Comment: @Reinmar I'm awarding you the bounty for the plugin suggestion. Still not done, but it will be done eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, one year later I came back and handled it differently. I took the justify plugin, and made a copy of it that only works the elements with which the original plugin doesn't. I had to modify it to suit my needs, but commenting the following out was a start(plugin.js):

```
if ( editor.blockless )
  return;
```

I don't know how interesting this is, but if anyone needs it, leave a comment and I'll post the entire source. It basically adds the text-align css to the editor element, instead of the inner block elements.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you are using Full CKEditor version